# Css dinámico en Oracle apex

Tags: css, apex

Quiero generar un calendario en apex , pero el color del evento está grabado en BD. O sea tengo grabado en tabla que para el día 1 tengo un evento cuyo estado es a y para otro día tengo grabado otro evento cuyo estado es b. Y por otro lado tengo una tabla donde al estado a le corresponde un determinado color y al estado b le corresponde otro color

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, te invito a realizar el [tour] para que conozcas mejor el funcionamiento del sitio. Para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida revisa [ask]

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo al tipo de evento puede definir un color para ser mostrado en la página del Calendario. En la consulta SQL puede obtener el color que requiere y en los atributos del Calendario seleccionar dicha columna:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También puede instalar la aplicación Group Calendar de la Galeria de Aplicaciones y ver más detalles relacionados al calendario.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]